# Computer freezes and blank screen on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

I have an old laptop with 2 GB of RAM and intel pentium at 2.13 HZ and it was running windows 7 and I decided to switch completely to ubuntu so I created a bootable USB and launched Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed it and everything is fine. Then I reboot and I receive a blank screen with ubuntu colours(orange/purple) and a total freeze , I tried to launch by holding shift key  then choosing ubuntu from GRUB menu but same issue what shall I do now
Thanks

Comment: What does ctrl+alt+F2 Yeild?

Comment: I would try `nomodeset` during boot (at grub, edit your entry & add it there as a kernel option [ie. `linux` line]).  I'd also suggest removing `quiet splash` from the line so more information is shown, and you can see more - but if new this may not help you.  With your RAM & cpu (I use dual-core-duo's too) I'd suggest a lighter flavor, eg. Xubuntu or Lubuntu (your tastes will dictate the best for you, even MATE, KDE .. as GNOME is rather heavy, but this is a personal choice)  -- if nomodeset works https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: the ctrl +alt+f2 yields nothing

Comment: I will give the nomodset a try